# Angular 4 loader does not work as expected

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I want to place loading gif before page is rendered. For that,I declare loaded variable in that component.Then hide my component as soon as the http requests are done (which sets loaded attribute to true in end). Hereafter loading gif disappears and component shows. I expect that first loading gif appear and then component. But the problem is that loading(becomes hidden) and component(become unhidden) at the Same time. I use low internet speed to check the problem and realized that loading shows only after the component is rendered. Please help to solve this awkward issue.

> The html file:

```
<loaders-css [loader]="'square-spin'" [loaderClass]="'my-loader'" 
 *ngIf="!loaded"></loaders-css> 

 <div class="container"  *ngIf="loaded">
        ..... 
 </div>
```

> The TypeScript File

```
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-user-info',
   templateUrl: './user-info.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./user-info.component.scss'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
   })
  export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  baseUrl= globalVars.baseUrl;
  token: any;
  apps: any;
  news: any;
  loaded = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService , private dashboardService: 
 DashboardService) { }
ngOnInit() {
 this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).userProfile;
 this.authService.getToken().then((token) => {this.token = token});
 this.dashboardService.getApplications().then( apps => {
  this.apps = apps.data;
});
this.dashboardService.getNews().then(news =>  {
  this.news = news.data;
});
 this.loaded = true;  
          }
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeeRU.gif)

Answer (score 1):

make a loded variable true inside your service call then it will work

```
this.dashboardService.getNews().then(news =>  {
  this.news = news.data;
  this.loaded = true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Arun. Thanks for reply.But it still does not work. The problem is that loading gif and component is loaded at the same time! look please at gif here.You can look at video describing situation below https://gifyu.com/image/zheH